# Copy table without data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select, query-performance

I am creating a temp table partially based on a structure from another (non temp) table. I need just the structure, not the data. In my research I found 2 SELECT statements that does what I need:

```
SELECT ID, Field1 FROM Table1 (NOLOCK) WHERE 0=1
```

and

```
SELECT TOP (0) ID, Field1 FROM Table1 (NOLOCK)
```

The performance difference is probably negligible, but I wanted to know which SELECT is more efficient?

Thanks

EDIT 1: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5057.00 (X64) 64-bit on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

EDIT 2: Execution plan for both statements looks exactly the same so I am guessing if there is difference in performance, it is negligible.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan?  If you are ever curious about performance that is typically the best place to start.

Comment: Is this using MS SQL Server? If so, what version? If not, then what RDBMS?

Comment: @ Abe Miessler What aspec(s) should I look in the execution plan? I am not an SQL expert (learned it on my own as I programmed)

Comment: @ Ryan Gates: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5057.00 (X64)   Mar 25 2011 13:33:31   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: Please always update the question with additional information rather than replying in the comment. Additionally MS SQL Server 2005 and 64-bit would be sufficient for this question.

Comment: @George -- The optimizer for SQL Server should treat these as the exact same execution plans.  I've always gone with a variation of the first, but I doubt it matters much.

Comment: And the `NOLOCK` in both is pointless as the plan won't touch the table rows at all. SQL Server can tell at compile time no rows will be returned and will replace the table access with a constant scan.

Comment: Thanks for the info sgeddes and thanks for the tip Martin Smith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both queries do a Constant Scan taking `0 ms`, so you should choose whichever one you and your team determine to be more clear and readable. In some cases, *performance* is not the most significant factor, but **maintainability** should always be considered. You should use this to guide your decision.

Based upon my personal preference, I would go with:

```
SELECT TOP (0) ID, Field1 FROM Table1 (NOLOCK)
```

The [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that demonstrates this can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74ae2/2).

Comment: Our DB has millions of records, so for us, priority #1 is performance. Since the performance in this case is not an issue, I agree with you on the `TOP (0)` - I like it much better then `0=1` approach.